# How to get the .zip file created in heroku app?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have created one app on heroku for Node.js.
When I run the app, it creates extension.zip file.
I need that file to put it as an Add on.
How can I get this file from Heroku?
Please help

Answer (score 1):

Your simplest strategy would be to set up an Express server, serve out a [static](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/static.html) directory, and save your zip file in there. Alternative, you can `heroku run bash` and then use `scp` on Heroku to copy the file to a different server. Of course, in production, you might want to consider using [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) or [jsftp](https://github.com/sergi/jsftp) to upload the file from your server.